# What different between assigning property on Object and Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript

What different between assigning property on Object and Object.prototype?
for example

```
Object.test =function(){};
```

and

```
Object.prototype.test =function(){}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Comment: this question only about Object

Comment: then remove `Object.prototype` from the title and from the question itself. Then you might as well delete the question. With more understanding you will understand that JS Objects are intrinsically linked to their prototype.

Comment: Word of caution: extending Object will cause all other objects to inherit from it and will mess with iterating with `for in` loops. Ideally you'd check hasOwnProperty() within the loop, but if you run a lot of dependencies, it's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Are you really assigning to `Object`, or is that just a stand-in identifier for some other object?

Comment: Given that `Object !== Object.prototype`, the observable difference is quite obvious. What are you really asking for here? Do you understand how prototypes work?

Answer (score 2):

The first gives `Object` a *static method* that can be invoked directly from the class, without an instance. For example:

```js
Object.test =function(){
  console.log('Object test running');
};

Object.test();
```

Assigning a function to the *prototype*, on the other hand, allows for *instances* to run the method:

```js
Object.prototype.test = function() {
  console.log('test running on object ', this);
};

// don't use the object constructor, this is just an example:
const obj = new Object();
obj.test();
```

It might make a bit more sense if you didn't use the built-in `Object`, which *everything* inherits from:

```js
function Foo() {}
Foo.checkIfFoo = function(arg) {
  return arg instanceof Foo;
};

const f = new Foo();
console.log(Foo.checkIfFoo(f));
```

Here, `foo.checkIfFoo` is a helper function on `Foo` that checks if a passed object is an instance of `Foo` or not - *no instance is required to run `checkIfFoo`*. Functions on the prototype, on the other hand, *require* an instance to run:

```js
function Foo() {
  this.info = 'A Foo instance';
}
Foo.prototype.checkInfo = function() {
  console.log(this.info);
};

const f = new Foo();
f.checkInfo();
```

Note that in ES6+, you can put a function directly on the class with the `static` keyword:

```js
// roughly equivalent to the snippet with checkIfFoo above
class Foo {
  static checkIfFoo(arg) {
    return arg instanceof Foo;
  }
}
const f = new Foo();
console.log(Foo.checkIfFoo(f));
```

Whereas a standard method lacks the `static` keyword:

```js
// roughly equivalent to the snippet with checkInfo above
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.info = 'A Foo instance';
  }
  checkInfo() {
    console.log(this.info);
  }
}
const f = new Foo();
f.checkInfo();
```